# JSF + WatchService + Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf-2, ejb, nio

I have tried nearly everything to get this work, but it seems that I don't get the right direction.

Here is the actual Situation: I use JSF2.2 with GlashFish7 under Netbeans7.3. My JSF application should create an second thread to run(Asynchronously) an endless loop. In this endless loop I use the WatchService (NIO) to check a specific folder for changes. 
The WatchService function works fine in a single thread driven jsf page. But I will do other stuff and during the loop, so I need this methode async, but i'm not able to run it in a seperad thread.

Here is my java class:

```
@Stateless
public class NewFile {

   @Asynchronous
   public void showNewFile() throws IOException{
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();        
        WatchKey watchKey = Paths.get("/home/user/input").register(watchService,new WatchEvent.Kind<?>[] { ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE });
        while (true) {
            try {
                watchKey = watchService.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException: " + ex);
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println(watchEvent.kind() + " " + ((Path) watchEvent.context()));
            }
            watchKey.reset();
        }
    }
}

In this class I call the methode:

@Named("startWatcher")
public class StartWatcher {

    private NewFile newFile;

    public void runSearcher() throws IOException{

        newFile.showNewFile();
    }
}
```

and the relevant section from thy index.xhtml

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{startWatcher.runSearcher()}" value="test"/>
```

I hope you understand my problem, I know my english isn't very good. i'm looking forward to receive a hint what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you should start a watchservice thread when your GlassFish domain is deployed by defining a @WebListener, for example:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private final NewFileRunner runner = new NewFileRunner();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        runner.startThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        runner.stopThread();
    }

    class NewFileRunner implements Runnable {

        private volatile Thread thread;
        private final WatchService watchService;

        public NewFileRunner() {
            watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Paths.get("/home/user/input").register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
        }

        /**
         * Start a worker thread to listen for directory changes.
         */
        public void startThread() {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        /**
         * Flag worker thread to stop gracefully.
         */
        public void stopThread() {
            if (thread != null) {
                Thread runningThread = thread;
                thread = null;
                runningThread.interrupt();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
            while (runningThread == thread) {
                WatchKey watchKey = null;
                try {
                    watchKey = watchService.take();
                    if (watchKey != null) {
                        for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                            System.out.println(watchEvent.kind() + " " + ((Path) watchEvent.context()));
                        }
                        watchKey.reset();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e = null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Of course, I'd refactor this out into multiple classes, but this will point you in the right direction.